# Is there a way to further parallelize kstreams aside from partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I understand that the fundamental approach to parallelization with kafka is to utilize partitioning. However, I have a special situation in that I have to leverage an existing infrastructure that only has 6 partitions, and I need to process millions and millions of records per second.

Is there a way to further optimize in a way that I could have each kstream consumer read and equally distribute load at the same time from a single partition?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to create a "helper" topic with the desired number of partitions. This topic can be configured with a very short retention time, because the original data is safely stored in the actual input topic. You use this helper topic to route all data through it and thus allow for more parallelism downstream:

```java
builder.stream("input-topic")
       .through("helper-topic-with-many-partitions")
       ... // actual processing
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what exactly this accomplishes, could you expand further?

Let's say we had 1 million records, in a single partition. From each record, we want fields a, b, and c. How can we parallelize reading a b and c from this single partition using kstreams (or .through).

Comment: The initial reading cannot be parallelized at all. You an only split the original stream/topic into sub-streams and parallelize afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions are the level of parallelization. With 6 partitions - you could maximum have 6 instances (of kstream) consuming data. If each instance is in a separate machine i.e. with 1 GBps network each, you could be reading in total with 600 Mbytes / sec

If that's not enough, you'd need to repartition data

Now for distributing your processing, you would need to run each kstream (with the same consumer group) on a different machine

Here's a short video that demonstrates how Kafka Streams (via Kafka SQL) are parallelized to 5 processes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=denwxORF3pU

It all depends on partitions & executors. With 6 partitions, I usually can achieve 500K+ messages / second, depending on the complexity of the processing of course

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the situation I am dealing with I cannot change the number of partitions of this topic. So I have to achieve maximum parallelism given a constraint of 6 partitions, in which I need to process several millions of messages per second. Also, it is a compacted topic, so I need to be able to quickly read from the beginning to the end as well.

Comment: 1 - make sure each partition leader is on a different broker
2 - use compression as the main bottleneck would be network i/o
3 - use 10 GBps network interfaces to be able to reach 6 * 10 Gbps max throughput
4 - use SSD in case there are a lot of disk seeks

Comment: Also you mention millions of messages / sec. Can you also mention msg / day on this topic i.e. are we talking about > 100 Billion msg / day ?